# kubernets pod using configmap before it's mounted

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

My code is below along with all the logs. In short my init pod seems to be attempting to run my setup.sh file, which is in a configmap, before it's mounted into the init pod. Does anyone have any guidance as to what the issue could be?

deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: two-containers
  labels:
    app: stockai
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: stockai
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: stockai
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: shared-data
          emptyDir: {}
      initContainers:
      - name: init-myservice
        image: alpine
        command:
          - "sh -c 'sleep 60; /app/setup.sh'"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: shared-data
            mountPath: /pod-data
```

configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    name: stock-ai-init-config
  name: stock-ai-init-config
  namespace: trading
data:
  setup.sh: |
    apk update
    apk upgrade
    apk add git
    git clone git@github.com:****/****/****
```

pod preset

```
apiVersion: settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: PodPreset
metadata:
  name: stock-ai-init
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: stockai
  volumeMounts:
    - name: setup
      mountPath: "/app/setup.sh"
      subPath: "setup.sh"
  volumes:
    - name: setup
      configMap:
        name: stock-ai-init-config
        defaultMode: 0777
```

kubctl log

```
$ kubectl describe po two-containers-6d5f4b4d85-blxqj

Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  5m22s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned trading/two-containers-6d5f4b4d85-blxqj to minikube
  Normal   Created    4m32s (x4 over 5m19s)  kubelet, minikube  Created container init-myservice
  Warning  Failed     4m32s (x4 over 5m19s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: failed to start container "init-myservice": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"sh -c 'sleep 60; /app/setup.sh'\": stat sh -c 'sleep 60; /app/setup.sh': no such file or directory": unknown
  Normal   Pulling    3m41s (x5 over 5m21s)  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "alpine"
  Normal   Pulled     3m40s (x5 over 5m19s)  kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "alpine"
  Warning  BackOff    10s (x23 over 5m1s)    kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command:` does not work like `docker run`, it is the kubernetes equivalent of the `CMD ["", ""]` in a Dockerfile and is fed to **exec**, not to **sh**; thus what you want is:

```yaml
        command:
          - sh
          - -c
          - 'sleep 60; /app/setup.sh'
```

Comment: that worked like a charm, thank you so much for explaining, I really appreciate it :)